# Advertisment in local IIS

Tags: iis

I set up IIS on my local computer (Win 7) that is connected to a WLAN router.
I created a simple test html with just a welcome message.

When I start the page locally, I get with Internet Explorer (not with Firefox)
on various places on the side advertisement. When I look the page source, I 
only can find the content, but no advertisement.

I run windows firewall and current antivirus software and have no add-ons in IE.
When I disconnect WLAN I don't get the advertisement, but also no empty frame.

Can this be from my WLAN router, is this a configuration is IIS or Internet Explorer?
How can I find this out?

Comment: It sounds like you have adware on your machine. Antivirus software often won't pick this up as some "legitimate" software carries along certain undesirables with it (Conduit, I'm looking at you).

Comment: @Nathan C This was it! Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have adware on your machine. Antivirus software often won't pick this up as some "legitimate" software carries along certain undesirables with it (Conduit, I'm looking at you).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get the advertisments using a diffferent browser, it should be related to IE and not to the hosting environment..

Have you tried resetting Internet Explorer (Options > Advanced, at the bottom)?